# Java and property overload

Tags: java, inheritance, properties, field

I'm stucked on this issue using eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) / Java 11 on debian 9

Let's state I've a base class

```
class A {

   private typeA prop;

   TypeA getProp(){
      return this.prop;
   }
}
```

and a derived one

```
class B extends A{
 private typeB prop;

 TypeB getProp(){
    return this.prop;
}
```

I'm expecting that prop in class B hides the prop in class A,  but in eclipse I've got an error Message in class B for the getProp method : 
**The return type is incompatible with A.getProp()**

any idea ?

Comment: You overrided `getProp`; name them differently.

Comment: Any method is not overridden if it just differs by return type.

Comment: Besides your issue your code does not compile, you have a method that returns `TypeB` and you're trying to return a variable of type `typeB`. Also you're missing semicolons.

Comment: I just don't want to name the differently .. why getProp() in class B does not overload getProp in class A ?

Comment: That would completely break polymorphism, and the Liskov principle. An A has a getProp() that returns a TypeA. B extends A. So any instance of B is an instance of A. So calling getProp() on a B instance must return a TypeA: that's the contract of the class A. Just take this code, that is supposed to work: `A a = new B(); TypeA typeA = a.getProp();`. Your code would make that impossible.

Comment: Your code would only be valid if TypeB extended TypeA.

Comment: ok JB Nizet so it's a design error that breaks java principles ?

Comment: Yes. Not just Java principles. OOP principles.

Comment: Methods cannot be overloaded based on just the return type.  It's not clear if inheritance is really needed here, or if a generic class would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot  JB nizet ... TypeB should extends TypeA .. that's  what I should have done . it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using JB Nizet comment through TypeA inheritance -> TypeB

Answer (score 0):

you can try using interfaces like this:

```
interface Type {
    // ...
}

class TypeA implements Type {
    // ...
}

class TypeB implements Type {
    // ...
} 

class A {

   private TypeA prop;

   Type getProp(){
      return this.prop;
   }
}

class B extends A {

    private TypeB prop;

    Type getProp(){
        return this.prop;
    }
}
```